# SQL - trying to find customers by spend group and then grouping those customers by their age and gender

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I have the below code which I am using to get the customer count, spend, transactions, and margin by their age and gender. I need to put another case statement so that I can also create groups of spend.

```
SELECT 
  gender, 
  agegroup, 
  Count(DISTINCT individual_id), 
  Count(DISTINCT transaction_number), 
  SUM(spend)
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      gender, 
      CASE WHEN age < 18 THEN '<18' WHEN age BETWEEN 18 
      AND 24 THEN '18-24' WHEN age BETWEEN 25 
      AND 32 THEN '25-32' WHEN age BETWEEN 33 
      AND 39 THEN '35-39' WHEN age BETWEEN 40 
      AND 46 THEN '40-46' WHEN age BETWEEN 47 
      AND 53 THEN '46-52' WHEN age BETWEEN 54 
      AND 60 THEN '53-58' WHEN age > 60 THEN '61+' END AS AGEGROUP, 
      individual_id,
      transaction_number, 
      spend
    FROM 
      (SELECT 
          gender, 
          age AS age, 
          a.individual_id as individual_id, 
          dollar_value_us as Spend, 
          transaction_number as transaction_number

          FROM transaction_detail_mv a
    join gender_details b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id)
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  gender, 
  agegroup 
ORDER BY 
  gender, 
  agegroup
```

Current results:

```
GENDER | AGEGROUP | COUNT(DISTINCTINDIVIDUAL_ID) | COUNT(DISTINCTTRANSACTION_NUMBER) | SUM(SPEND)
:----- | :------- | ---------------------------: | --------------------------------: | ---------:
F      | 46-52    |                            1 |                                 2 |         22
M      | 18-24    |                            1 |                                 1 |         11
M      | 40-46    |                            2 |                                 6 |         62
```

So instead of filtering on the entire query to find the number of customers who sepdn between $10-$23 like below: I just need a query which would divide the data into spend cohorts.

```
select * from (SELECT 
  gender, 
  agegroup, 
  Count(DISTINCT individual_id), 
  Count(DISTINCT transaction_number), 
  SUM(spend) as spend
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      gender, 
      CASE WHEN age < 18 THEN '<18' WHEN age BETWEEN 18 
      AND 24 THEN '18-24' WHEN age BETWEEN 25 
      AND 32 THEN '25-32' WHEN age BETWEEN 33 
      AND 39 THEN '35-39' WHEN age BETWEEN 40 
      AND 46 THEN '40-46' WHEN age BETWEEN 47 
      AND 53 THEN '46-52' WHEN age BETWEEN 54 
      AND 60 THEN '53-58' WHEN age > 60 THEN '61+' END AS AGEGROUP, 
      individual_id,
      transaction_number, 
      spend
    FROM 
      (SELECT 
          gender, 
          age AS age, 
          a.individual_id as individual_id, 
          dollar_value_us as Spend, 
          transaction_number as transaction_number

          FROM transaction_detail_mv a
    join gender_details b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id)
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  gender, 
  agegroup 
ORDER BY 
  gender, 
  agegroup) where spend between 10 and 20
```

The Spend cohorts which I am looking for are:

```
<$10
$10-$20
$20-$30
$30-$40
$40+
```

This is the fiddle link:

**https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fe7bbe67da923fde05b5daf8ad991e7c**

So for example, x number of customers fall within $10-$40 spend range who are female and belong to 18-24 age range. This is what I am ultimately trying to get to. Is there a way to incorporate this in my current query ??

any help would be appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: Please show us the result that you are currently getting, and the result that you expect. It might also be a good idea to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) so others can efficiently play around with your data.

Comment: @GMB I have added the fiddle link. also I do not have a result to show but I just want to create a format which shows me the customer count, transaction count  by their spend range, gender and age

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
    SELECT 
      gender, 
      agegroup, 
      Count(DISTINCT individual_id) customer_count, 
            CASE WHEN SUM(spend) < 10 THEN '<$10' WHEN SUM(spend) >= 10 
          AND SUM(spend) < 20 THEN '$10-$20' WHEN SUM(spend) >= 20 
          AND SUM(spend) < 30 THEN '$20-$30' WHEN SUM(spend) >= 30 
          AND SUM(spend) < 40 THEN '$30-$40' WHEN SUM(spend) >= 40 THEN '$40+' END AS spendgroup
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          gender, 
          CASE WHEN age < 18 THEN '<18' WHEN age BETWEEN 18 
          AND 24 THEN '18-24' WHEN age BETWEEN 25 
          AND 32 THEN '25-32' WHEN age BETWEEN 33 
          AND 39 THEN '35-39' WHEN age BETWEEN 40 
          AND 46 THEN '40-46' WHEN age BETWEEN 47 
          AND 53 THEN '46-52' WHEN age BETWEEN 54 
          AND 60 THEN '53-58' WHEN age > 60 THEN '61+' END AS AGEGROUP, 
          individual_id,
          spend
        FROM 
          (SELECT 
              gender, 
              age, 
              a.individual_id, 
              dollar_value_us as Spend
             FROM transaction_detail_mv a
        join gender_details b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id)
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      gender, 
      agegroup
    ORDER BY 
      gender, 
      agegroup;
```

Output:

```
    |GENDER |AGEGROUP   |CUSTOMER_COUNT |SPENDGROUP |
    |F      |46-52      |1              |$20-$30    |   
    |M      |18-24      |1              |$10-$20    |
    |M      |40-46      |2              |$40+       |
```

DB Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7371387decf322b567287e42e0b864d)

Comment: not really, I would like to create the spend cohorts first for each customer and then add their age group and gender to it instead of summing up the sales and then creating spend cohorts.

Comment: @Somya please share your expected output in the format above